# Avoid sourceMap files

Tags: typescript, gulp, tsc

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app/source/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

As you can see the sourceMap option is set to `true`, this is because I need it to debug my application.

But I need it only in *debug mode* so that I would like to set it to false when I run my *release mode* gulp script.

Is there any way to force `--sourceMap=fase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you past example of code of your gulp tasks - gulp, gulp dist?

I suggest you should use the plugin [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) and in gulp watch (default dev task) use him with plugin [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps). In gulp dist (or whatever task) you simply skip the gulp-sourcemaps pipeline, so in dist version you will have no sourcemaps.

Or you can simply use two different tsconfig files - dev / prod. And use them like [gulp-typescript#using-tsconfigjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#using-tsconfigjson)